# Cant find Android NDK version 21.3.6528147 for unity 2022.1.10f1

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-ndk

I downloaded and installed unity **2022.1.10f1** using links found in :
https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/2022.1.10

I am developing for android using windows os,
so I downloaded both unity editor installers:
https://download.unity3d.com/download_unity/9aa0f82c4f96/Windows64EditorInstaller/UnitySetup64.exe

and android target support:
https://download.unity3d.com/download_unity/9aa0f82c4f96/TargetSupportInstaller/UnitySetup-Android-Support-for-Editor-2022.1.10f1.exe

but the problem is, android target support does not include android NDK required for building android apks.

to find what specific version of android NDK required for this release of unity, after launching Unity editor I went to: `Edit -> Preferences -> External Tools` tab, and I went down to: Android NDK section, unticked "`Android NDK installed with unity (recommended)`, and It shows me the required version of NDK. which in this case is: **21.3.6528147** as shown in the photo here

[image]

*Unity recommends that I download Unity SDK and all of its relaated modules using Unity Hub: https://public-cdn.cloud.unity3d.com/hub/prod/UnityHubSetup.exe but there are sometimes when you have a limited internet package and you want to download offline installers for unity and modules so that you can re-install them if needed later on.*

I looked on the internet for download link for that NDK version, but I can't find it.

I hope you can help.

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the link :
using Android Studio -> configure -> SDK Manager -> Android SDK -> SDK Tools, and then tick on "Show package details", then scroll down to "NDK (side by side)", and then tick on the required version. in my case: 21.3.6528147 as shown in the image bellow
[image]

and then press apply. It will bring you a confirmation screen, confirm it. then it will start downloading the file, and will show you a download screen like this screen:

[image]

now I can see the correct download link, which in this case is :

https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r21d-windows-x86_64.zip

I copied that link and stopped the downloaded. I used an external download manager to download the file and keep it offline. After the download had finished I extracted the file into a directory and set unity to look to that directory for Android NDK. as shown here:

[image]

This stopped me for some time, and I thought I should share it with you.

I hope it helps someone.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For "Mac M1 Silicon" Download link for NDK (21.3.6528147) is https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r21d-darwin-aarch64.zip